# check if the record exists in database

Tags: java, sql

I need to check the box no if exist in the database under the remittance id that I enter if the box no exists then i need to show the message that the box no already exists but if it doesn't the it should insert new box i have written some code but its showing error

```
private void txtboxnoFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    DBUtil util = new DBUtil();

    try {
        Connection con = util.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
            "select box_no from dbo.soil_det where rm_id = ? and box_no = ?");
        stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(tf_rm_id.getText()));
        stmt.setString(1, (txtboxno.getText()));       
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            rs.equals().txtboxno.getText());
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "hello!S");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DATAENTRY.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: it should probably be stmt.setString(2, ...

Comment: Actually what's the error you were getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
private void txtboxnoFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
DBUtil util = new DBUtil();

try {
    Connection con = util.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "select box_no from dbo.soil_det where rm_id = ? and box_no = ?");
    stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(tf_rm_id.getText()));
    stmt.setString(2, (txtboxno.getText()));       
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
    bool recordAdded = false;
    while(!rs.next()){            
       /// Do your insertion of new records
         recordAdded = true;
    }
    if( recordAdded ){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Record added");
    }else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Record already exists");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DATAENTRY.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the appropriate record from the `ResultSet` e.g.

```
boolean found = rs.getString(1).equals().txtboxno.getText());
```

At the moment you're simply comparing the `ResultSet` object itself to a string, and that won't work. The above pulls the first record from the `ResultSet` and performs the comparison on that (note: your datatype may be different and you may need `rs.getInt(1)` etc.)

Perhaps its sufficient in your case just to check if you have a `ResultSet` result (via `rs.next()`)

Comment: also rs.wasNull() too is required?

Answer (score 0):

or you could use a count:

```
String query = "select count(*) 
from dbo.soil_det where rm_id = ? and box_no = ?";
```

then after executing the query you get the count with

```
                   rs.getInt(1)
```

using that you can decide which info to show to the user

Answer (score 0):

very First You have to get count using sql if count is greater than zero then do not insert records and show message like already exists and in else part insert record. see following example

```
private boolean findCount(int rm_id,String box_no)
{
      int count=0;
     //write query here 
     count = assign query result;
     //check count 
if(count>0)
{
     return false;//records exists
}else{
    return true;//records do not exists
}
```

}

```
public void insertData()
{
     if(findCount(1,"1")){//pass values
       //Write down your insert logic
     }else{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Records Already Exists");
     }
}
```

Note: Friend in Your Example you have not written the insert logic. only select was there

Answer (score 0):

First you could add -- on the db table -- a unique constrain on the columns (rm_id, box_no), this is anyway a good thing to do.

Then you could simply try to insert the box and catch the exception and check if it is a violation of the unique constraint.

Another option (still keeping the unique constraint) would be to make a more complicated SQL insert statement that inserts only if not existing, you may google "sql insert if not exist" to find some examples...

Answer (score 0):

simplified version

```
private void txtboxnoFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
DBUtil util = new DBUtil();

try {
    Connection con = util.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "select box_no from dbo.soil_det where rm_id = ? and box_no = ?");
    stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(tf_rm_id.getText()));
    stmt.setString(2, (txtboxno.getText()));       
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
    if(!rs.next()){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Record added");
    }else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Record already exists");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DATAENTRY.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

- rs.next() followed by if condition returns `true` if the record exists in a table. if not, return `false`.